# Use an object from the parents document inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript

I create an object in a document during thje onload event for the body and then later an iframe.  I need to have access to that object (with all methods) inside that iframe.

in the parent document (init.html):

```
function qvinit() {
qva = new Qva.PageBinding('QLM');}
```

in the body of init.html I then create an iframe and call another HTML page

```
<iframe src=nextpage.html></iframe>
```

nextpage.html then is a very simple document which loads some javascript functions and CSS and which basically only does a DIV

```
<div class="QvFrame" avqview="QLM" avq="object:.Document\CH01" id="Document\CH01" style="width:260px;height:158px"></div>
```

this DIV section works well if it resides within the parent document (i.e. init.html). however, i need to put it into a "child document" (i.e. nextpage.html) and then it doesn't work anymore. It might be that nextpage.html doesn't know anything about the object, I don't know as I'm still very new to Javascript.

Does someone have an idea how to accomplish it that I can use the QLM object from the parant document?

Many thanks

Stefan

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for:

```
window.parent.qva
```

That should be a reference to the variable qva, assuming both the fram and the parent are on the same host.

I've used a class in the past the creates an array of stored objects across all frames and open windows - you might want to look into doing that.